# Access VBA/Prevent duplicate values

Tags: ms-access, vba

How I can prevent duplicate values to not insert into the table. I have created a code to INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE and I want to display a MsgBox that there is a duplicate value and to cancel it. Thanks. Below you have the code:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()

    If Me.emID.Tag & "" = "" Then

        If (IsNull(Me.emID) Or (Me.emID = "") Or IsNull(Me.emFirst) Or (Me.emFirst = "") Or IsNull(Me.emLast) Or (Me.emLast = "")) Then
            Me.emID.BorderColor = vbRed
            Me.emFirst.BorderColor = vbRed
            Me.emLast.BorderColor = vbRed
            MsgBox "Please fill required fields", vbInformation, "Information"
            Exit Sub
        End If


            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblEmployees(emID, first, last, gender, phone, mobphone, city, state, zip, adress, email, comment)" & _
            "VALUES ('" & Me.emID & "', '" & Me.emFirst & "', '" & Me.emLast & "', '" & Me.emGender & "', '" & Me.emPhone & "', '" & Me.emMob & "', '" & Me.emCity & "', '" & Me.emState & "', '" & Me.emZip & "', '" & Me.emAdress & "', '" & Me.emEmail & "', '" & Me.emComment & "')"
            MsgBox "Record Added", vbInformation, "information"

            Else
                CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblEmployees " & _
                "SET emiD =" & Me.emID & _
                ", first ='" & Me.emFirst & "'" & _
                ", last = '" & Me.emLast & "'" & _
                ", gender ='" & Me.emGender & "'" & _
                ", phone = '" & Me.emPhone & "'" & _
                ", mobphone ='" & Me.emMob & "'" & _
                ", city ='" & Me.emCity & "'" & _
                ", state ='" & Me.emState & "'" & _
                ", zip ='" & Me.emZip & "'" & _
                ", adress ='" & Me.emAdress & "'" & _
                ", email ='" & Me.emEmail & "'" & _
                ", comment ='" & Me.emComment & "'" & _
                "WHERE emID =" & Me.emID.Tag
                MsgBox "Updated!", vbInformation, "Information"
    End If

Me.tblEmployees_subform.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Comment: Very easy: when a new value is inserted, first try to select it. If the result of the selection is not empty, then it means it's a duplicate and you don't allow the rest of the code to run. Note: you're exposed to [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), if your data might be at risk, consider using parametric SQL (I don't know if the AdoDB of VBA provides though, maybe try to clean the insertion yourself if not).

Comment: You either query the database first, to see if a different record already matches what you're going to insert/update. Or add constraints to the table not allowing duplicates as you define them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your SQL to use IF EXISTS condition and insert only if the records does not already exists.

Your SQL may look like:

IF NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT ......
        )

```
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblEmployees ......<insert since employee does not exists>
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd like to update an employee if one exists for the given ID otherwise you'd like to add a new employee. You can prevent adding duplicate employees by first trying to update an employee record with the given ID and if no records were updated only then do you add a new employee record.

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()
    If (IsNull(Me.emID) Or (Me.emID = "") Or IsNull(Me.emFirst) Or (Me.emFirst = "") Or IsNull(Me.emLast) Or (Me.emLast = "")) Then
        Me.emID.BorderColor = vbRed
        Me.emFirst.BorderColor = vbRed
        Me.emLast.BorderColor = vbRed
        MsgBox "Please fill required fields", vbInformation, "Information"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' You must set CurrentDb to a variable otherwise the RecordsAffected
    ' property used later will be incorrect.
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb

    ' First try to update an existing employee.
    db.Execute _
        "UPDATE tblEmployees " & _
        "SET first ='" & Me.emFirst & "', " & _
            "last = '" & Me.emLast & "', " & _
            "gender ='" & Me.emGender & "', " & _
            "phone = '" & Me.emPhone & "', " & _
            "mobphone ='" & Me.emMob & "', " & _
            "city ='" & Me.emCity & "', " & _
            "state ='" & Me.emState & "', " & _
            "zip ='" & Me.emZip & "', " & _
            "adress ='" & Me.emAdress & "', " & _
            "email ='" & Me.emEmail & "', " & _
            "comment ='" & Me.emComment & "'" & _
        "WHERE emID =" & Me.emID.Tag & ";"

    ' If no records were affected by update then add a new employee.
    If db.RecordsAffected = 0 Then
        db.Execute _
            "INSERT INTO tblEmployees(emID, first, last, gender, phone, mobphone, city, state, zip, adress, email, comment) " & _
            "VALUES ('" & Me.emID & "', '" & Me.emFirst & "', '" & Me.emLast & "', '" & Me.emGender & "', '" & Me.emPhone & "', '" & Me.emMob & "', '" & Me.emCity & "', '" & Me.emState & "', '" & Me.emZip & "', '" & Me.emAdress & "', '" & Me.emEmail & "', '" & Me.emComment & "');"
        MsgBox "Record Added", vbInformation, "Information"
    Else
        MsgBox "Updated!", vbInformation, "Information"
    End If

    Me.tblEmployees_subform.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Note: In the update query I removed the update to the emID field since that is what the query is based on (in the WHERE clause). If the emID field is changing you won't be able to use the new emID value to find an employee record with the old emID value.

If you never want any duplicates I would also suggest that you add constraints to your database table to prevent duplicates, as suggested by Daniel Cook. I would also suggest looking into using parameterized queries instead of building SQL strings in VBA.

Comment: I was just about to post an identical solution. It may be prudent to let the OP know that the update to the `emiD ` field is useless since that is the field the update is being based upon.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't paying close enough attention to the contents of the queries and didn't catch that.